# R Programming - Access Count Value in Bar Chart

Tags: r, count, bar-chart

I have a bar chart, where the X axis has the city and the Y axis has the automatically determined count of the cities appearing in the data.

```
    bigger_data <- read.csv(file.choose()) ## public_record_2_xlax
    bigger_data <- drop_na(bigger_data)

    bigger_data %>% arrange(Total.Value) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=City)) +
      geom_bar()
```

Is there any way to access the value of the count variable on the Y-axis?

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't try to extract variables from a plot object. `table(bigger_data$City)` should do what you want, or `bigger_data %>% count(City)` if you prefer tidyverse

Comment: I added a new variable, count2, and extracted the value as you said. 

`count2 <- table(bigger_data$City)`

When I put this value in the Y argument of the GG plot, it says the length is not the same, it should graph the same bar plot.

`bigger_data %>% arrange(Total.Value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=City, y=count2)) +
  geom_bar()`

Isn't should graph the same?

Comment: Try `count2 <- bigger_data %>% count(City)` Then you could have `ggplot(count2, aes(City, n)) + geom_col()`